# Concat objects in jsx of react with comma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have an user object like this

```
user: {
name: "james",
contact: "3245234545",
email: "james@gmail.com"
}
```

and I want to display it like this

```
james, 3245234545, james@gmail.com
```

if it's an array I can do join(',') but it's an object unfortunately. My current approach is like this

```
{this.user &&
<div>
{this.user.name} ,{this.user.contact}, {this.user.email}
</div>
}
```

This will work but not perfect, what if user did not fill in their contact? then the extra `,` is still there. if the email is optional, then there will be an extra `,` too in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.keys`:

```
{this.user &&
<div>
{Object.keys(this.user).map(key => this.user[key]).join(', ')}
</div>
}
```

There is also [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), but it not very well supported, so you'd have to use a polyfill for that.

Also note that the order of object keys may not be the exact order you defined them in, although most browsers will preserve the order, you may want to use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead.

Comment: this won't work if the user object has other stuff like id, address, grade etc.

Comment: Well, that wasn't in the question... But you could use something like lodash `_.pick(this.user, ['name', 'contact', 'email'])` to pick the keys you want first.